# How can I show randomly different data for each user in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a tag system in Django with the following model;

```
class Data(models.Model):
    new = models.ChardField()
    is_tagged = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Tag(models.Model):
    data = models.ForeignKey(Data,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="data")
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name="New Status",max_length=10,null=True)
```

The tag status holds "positive", "negative", and "pass".

There is a page called "new tags" and around 100 users will enter the page at the same time.

There are 10000 data and users will enter the page and just click "positive", "negative", and "pass".

I want to show different data for each user.

`EDIT`

```
New1: id = 1,is_tagged=False

New2: id = 2,is_tagged=False
```

```
User 1: Display New1

User 2: Display New1
```

```
User 1: Tag: "Positive" and id = 1, is_tagged will be "True"

Because both user open the windows at the same time, after 1 second,

User 2: Tag: "Pass" and id = 1 , is_tagged will be "False"
```

I want to prevent this situation. It supposed to be;

```
User 1: Display New1
```

```
User 2: Display New2
```

So each user must display different News Data to tag.

Let's say a user tagged the new as "positive". If I will send the new with `random()` it can be the same at another user unluckily. And the user can tag as "pass". This status will make "Data" "is_tagged" False. But other users tagged "positive" before.

How can I prevent users see the same data at the same time?

Comment: ```It will prevent the users not seeing the same data and tagging the data 2 times.``` can you please explain more about this line?

Comment: @shivankgtm I add more information. With "EDIT".

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get a random object, you could do something like:

```
import random 

all_object_ids = Data.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True) # gets list of all object ids

random_id = random.choice(all_object_ids) # picks a random id from list

random_tag = Data.objects.get(id=random_id)
```